# Minor confusion regarding Work-energy theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I have been studying about WET for sometime and have a small doubt.

WET states that the total work done on a system is change in the KE of the system.
Let's say there are forces F1,F2,F3... acting on a system, then according to wet (F1+F2+F3...)r=W=change in KE [assuming forces and r in same direction]

Can I say that, the total change in KE of the system is equal to the sum of the changes in KE due to work(s) done by F1,F2...(as in KE= KE1 +KE2... where KE1= W by force F1[F1r], KE2=W by force F2[F2r] and so on)
P.S where ever i mention KE, i mean change in KE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WET states that the total work done on a system is change in the KE of the system

Usually the term is “net work”, meaning the work done by the net force. Total work would usually be the sum of the works from each individual force. Those are very different, in general.

> assuming forces and r in same direction

It is not necessary to assume they are in the same direction if you use the dot product: $$(\vec F_1 + \vec F_2 + \vec F_3 + …)\cdot \vec r = \vec F_{net}\cdot \vec r = W_{net}=\Delta KE$$ where $\vec r$ is the displacement of the center of mass.

> Can I say that, the total change in KE of the system is equal to the sum of the changes in KE due to work(s) done by F1,F2...(as in KE= KE1 +KE2... where KE1= W by force F1[F1r], KE2=W by force F2[F2r] and so on) P.S where ever i mention KE, i mean change in KE.

Yes, you can distribute over the multiplication

$$(\vec F_1 + \vec F_2 + \vec F_3 + …)\cdot \vec r = \vec F_1 \cdot \vec r + \vec F_2 \cdot \vec r + \vec F_3 \cdot \vec r + …  $$

Again, $\vec r$ here is the displacement of the center of mass, not the displacement of the point of application of the force

Comment: The question is about the work-energy theorem for a system of particles, which states that sum of all work terms due to all forces on all particles equals change of total KE of all particles in the system. Thus the question is using "total work" correctly.

Comment: Your example with net force works only if there is no total contribution to work due to internal forces, thus, only for solid body. Work-energy theorem is more general than that.

Comment: @JánLalinský that is not the usual one I have seen, but there is a wide variety

Comment: Thank you so much,this clears a lot.

Comment: on a side note why is net work (as you said work done by net force)  and total work (as you said sum of the works from each individual force) different from each other.Can you give me an example where this is true, i am having a hard time to visualize this case

Comment: @hexusXDX they are different any time the point of application of the force moves differently from the center of mass. For example, a person jumping vertically. The net force is the sum of gravity and the normal force. The KE increases as the displacement of the CoM is in the direction of the net force. But the normal force does no work and the gravitational force does negative work. So the total work is negative even though the net work is positive. The decrease in chemical energy accounts for both the increase in KE and the negative work from gravity

Comment: I see, Thank you